# Rendering a Static Page in Yii that resides in the Current Theme's Views

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

Ok I have a controller class in Yii that I want to use a different view folder aside from using its default view folder.

The natural behavior is when a `$this->render("<view file>");` you would use the following to navigate your view file in the project...

> "//" navigates project default view folder
>
> "/" navigates current theme view folder
>
> or do not use anything to select a view automatically in the
>   controller's default view folder

but my problem is i'm not rendering a **view file** but a **STATIC PAGE** that resides in `/pages` folder of a certain view folder. The static page I want to navigate is a static page the resides **in my current theme folder** views but the default is the controller navigates the static page inside the `/protected/view` folder

I tried also this override to modify the controller's view folder. I put this code in my controller that I want to render static pages in a theme folder

```
public function init(){
    $this->layout = "//layouts/script";
    $this->viewPath = "/js";
}
```

but the problem is the viewPath is readOnly variable.

> *Now my question is how I can render static pages that resides in my current theme's view folders?*

NOTE: please if you don't understand my question, please don't down vote. I'm open to change and explain my problem for you as possible as I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're overriding the `actions` method in your `SiteController`, somehow, you need to change the `CViewAction`'s [basePath](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CViewAction#basePath-detail) property. It defaults to pages, as the documentation says.

Could you try something like this?

```
 public function actions()
 {
     return array(
        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
            'basePath'=>'path/to/your/theme/folder'
        ),
     );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

create a helper class for yourself and declare this method (change filepaths and other stuff):

```
public static function renderInternal($_viewFile_, $_data_ = null, $_return_ = false) {
        // we use special variable names here to avoid conflict when extracting data
        if (is_array($_data_)) {
            extract($_data_, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, 'data');
        } else {
            $data = $_data_;
        }

        $viewsDir = '/protected/views/internals/';

        if ($_return_) {
            ob_start();
            ob_implicit_flush(false);
            require(getcwd() . $viewsDir . $_viewFile_ . '.php');
            return ob_get_clean();
        } else {
            require(getcwd() . $viewsDir . $_viewFile_ . '.php');
        }
    }
```

Use it/call it:

```
MyHelperClass::renderInternal( 'myviewfile', array( /* YOUR DATA */ ), /* RETURN CONTENTS OR NOT */ )
```

**NOTE**: Change `$viewsDir` to your desired directory.

Comment: my problem is static pages do not use any function to be rendered.. it just declared in the controller with something like this

 `'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),`

Answer (score 1):

try this in your any site controller or any controller..

```
 public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),
        );
    }
```

or refer this link...

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/22/how-to-display-static-pages-in-yii/
```

Comment: so what problem you exactly facing ??